# Adobe AIR: problem with OpenID / rpxnow logins

Tags: openid, air, rpxnow

Does Adobe Air work with OpenID/rpxnow?

I'm having a developer build me an AIR app to work with my website so I can have access to desktop photos.

However, my site uses OpenID logins via the rpxnow.com implementation. Works fine in the web version, but my developer has told me that he cannot do rpxnow/openid logins from the AIR app because it doesn't allow pop-ups and/or redirects.

Has anyone found a workaround?

m.

Answer (score 0):

There are many implementations of OpenID for Adobe Flex.  Just google Flex OpenID and you'll find lots of results.

http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2009.02.17.html

OpenID is slightly more complicated in a desktop app than in a web app due to how OpenID works, but it's still doable.  OpenID redirects from the signing-in site to the authenticating site and then back to the signing-in site.  Since the desktop app is a desktop app and not a site, the authenticating site can't really redirect back to the app.  But the app can provide a fake redirect url and then hook into the browser component events to listen for a redirect back to this fake url, and when it's detected finish the authentication.

Comment: I'm very wary about any desktop app that claims to do OpenID.  I betcha it's not secure and neither is the web site that allows access to its data in this way.  OAuth is the way to go for this scenario.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott, I agree it's less secure but the website has no way to know if a custom desktop app is behind the http request vs a standard browser (or even if there is a browser plugin interacting with the request and possibly saving form data).  All the website sees is http headers and form fields.  It's up to the user to decide if they want to enter their credentials or not.